# How to preserve all leading indents in yaml?

Tags: java, yaml

I would like for the user to be able to specify a block scalar style string and keep all the leading indents they specified.

### Current Input

```
SomeText: |
            This is some text that I would like for
            The leading indents to be preserved.
            It would be really nice for the leading indents to be preserved.
```

### Expected Output

```
            This is some text that I would like for
            The leading indents to be preserved.
            It would be really nice for the leading indents to be preserved.
```

### Actual Output

```
This is some text that I would like for
The leading indents to be preserved.
It would be really nice for the leading indents to be preserved.
```

As you can see when I parse the YAML using a YAML library in **Java** the leading indents are not preserved but I would like to preserve them. **How can I do this?**

I think I would need to use a block indentation indicator but the YAML spec is so confusing. Could anyone explain block indentation indicators for dummies? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a block indentation indicator:

```yaml
SomeText: |1
            This is some text that I would like for
            The leading indents to be preserved.
            It would be really nice for the leading indents to be preserved.
```

This explicitly specifies the indentation of the scalar content relative to the surrounding indentation, i.e. in this case, the block scalar's indentation is defined to be 1 more than `SomeText:`. Everything after the first space is interpreted as content, not indentation, and will be part of the scalar's value.

Mind that the indentation indicator must be at least 1 because the block scalar's indentation must be at least 1 more than the surrounding indentation, since it would end at anything having the surrounding indentation (or lesser). You can never preserve whitespace that is interpreted as indentation (which would be contrary to the idea of indentation) but you can still put an arbitrary amount of whitespace in front of your lines by adding whitespace.

Comment: wait wouldnt this mean if the user specified 12 spaces of indentation (or leading indentation) (3 tabs), the output would only have 11 spaces of leading indentation? Im sort of still confused about how block indentation indicators work

Comment: @chid00 Don't confuse indentation in the YAML sense (i.e. whitespace that is *not* content) with „indentation in the output“ (i.e. whitespace that *is* content and hence will be written to the output). `1` means that *one* space of the following lines will not be part of the content. The amount of spaces that *are* part of the content depends on how many spaces are following after that first space.